# SPException User cannot be found rest api

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, user

Hoping you can help, I currently have a REST query that returns a number of items however this is currently returning 'User cannot be found'

```
{
    "odata.error": {
        "code": "-2146232832, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-US",
            "value": "User cannot be found."
        }
    }
}
```

The query I am currently running is using TypeScript and a GET call to return file properties using the server relative url, I am making the following call:

> /_api/web/getFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/Intranet/ManagedDocuments/My Document.docx')?**$select**=*,ListItemAllFields/*,ListItemAllFields/ContentType/Id,ListItemAllFields/ContentType/Name,Versions
>   **&$expand**=ListItemAllFields,ListItemAllFields/ContentType,Author,ModifiedBy,CheckedOutByUser,Versions

If I remove Author from the rest call then the response is as expected, I have checked the **user information list** and the author of the document exists so I would expect this to work.

I appreciate any help that can be given with this.

Comment: Same issue occured recently for our clients. Could this error be caused by some kind of update in SharePoint Online?